# Ansible custom nested loops with subelements

Tags: ansible

This is brief and expressive data structure in my `vars/main.yml` file:

```
webapp_dirs:
  - /var/www/example.com
  - /var/www/test.example.ru

webapp_acls:
  - dirs:
    - app
    - web
    - src
    - vendor
    perm: rX
    recursive: yes
  - dirs:
    - app/cache
    - app/logs
    perm: rwX
    recursive: no
```

I want to iterate over first list, then over second list, and finally over nested list in second list:

```
for top_dir in webapp_dirs:
    for acl in webapp_acls:
        for dir in i.dirs:
               ....
```

I have `with_subelements` and `with_nested`, but they can not be combined. Is there any way to do what I want in ansible?

**UPD**

@chrism gave me a good idea, but I can not make outer loop work:

```
- include: app-permissions.yml
  vars:
    webapp_dir: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - /var/www/example.com
```

`app-permissions.yml` contains inner loop over variables. This fails with error `{"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! an unexpected type error occurred. Error was can only concatenate list (not \"str\") to list"}`

Comment: Please, move this question to http://serverfault.com/, I posted it to the wrong site and have not enough reputation here to move it myself.

Comment: I think it's ok on SO. Most Ansible questions end here. Also any possible answer would be best suited on SO, because you can not do it with the built in loops of Ansible. You will need to [create your own lookup plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins) for that.

Answer (score 2):

In ansible 2.0 you can have nested loops via `- include playbook.yml`. Where the outerloop includes `playbook.yml` and the inner loop is in `playbook.yml`

Comment: Good idea, but I can not make outer loop work, see question update